# Problem to merge multiple streamings in the same table on apache iceberg

Tags: apache-spark, spark-streaming, apache-iceberg

I have multiple spark streaming writing in the same table in different fields. The iceberg documentation said the following: **Iceberg supports multiple concurrent writes using optimistic concurrency.**

But the error message appear when trying to merge:

> Caused by: org.apache.iceberg.exceptions.ValidationException: Found conflicting files that can contain records matching true

***Spark Merge:***

```
spark.sql(
  f"""
  MERGE INTO datahub.replicacao.pefin_table tgt
  USING (select nu_documento, co_cadus, aud_enttyp, nu_particao from pefin_pf) src
  ON tgt.nu_documento = src.nu_documento and src.nu_particao in ('1', '2', '4')
  WHEN MATCHED AND src.aud_enttyp = 'D' THEN DELETE
  WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE SET *
  WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN INSERT *
""")
```

***Spark Session Configs*:**

```
 val spark = SparkSession.builder()
.master("local[*]")
.config("spark.sql.catalog.datahub", "org.apache.iceberg.spark.SparkSessionCatalog")
.config("spark.sql.catalog.datahub.type", "hadoop")
.config("spark.sql.catalog.datahub", "org.apache.iceberg.spark.SparkCatalog")
.config("spark.sql.catalog.datahub.warehouse", "file:///C:/dev/warehouse")
.config("spark.sql.extensions", "org.apache.iceberg.spark.extensions.IcebergSparkSessionExtensions")
.getOrCreate()
```